# Type variable to be unified occurs in type

Tags: types, compiler-errors, sml, unification

I have a function to reconstruct a tree from 2 lists. I return a list on all branches, but I am getting an error that I don't understand. But I assume it has to do with the return types.

The error is this:

```
Can't unify ''a with ''a list (Type variable to be unified occurs in type) Found near recon
( ::( preoH, preoT), ::( inoH, ...))
Exception- Fail "Static errors (pass2)" raised
```

The line the error occurs at is the headline of the function definition `fun recon (preoH::preoT, inoH::inoT) =`

What does that error mean exactly and why does it occur?

```
(* Reconstruts a binary tree from an inorder and a preorder list. *)
fun recon (preoH::preoT, inoH::inoT) =
  (* Case 0: Leaf reached*)
  if
      preoT = [] andalso inoT = [] andalso preoH = inoH
  then
      [preoH]
  else
      let
      (* split the list of nodes into nodes to the left and nodes to the
      right of preoH; ST stands for subtree *)
      val (inoLST, inoRST) = splitat (inoH::inoT, preoH)
      val (preoLST, preoRST) = splitafter (preoT, last(inoLST))
      in
      (* Case 1: Unary branch encountered, make preoH the parent node of the
      subtree and combine the left and right preorder and inorder lists*)
      if
              length(inoLST) <> length(preoLST)
      then
          [preoH, recon (preoLST@preoRST, inoLST@inoRST)]
      (* Case 2: Binary branch encountered, proceed as normal *)
      else
              [recon (preoLST, inoLST), preoH, recon (preoRST, inoRST)]
      end;
```

Comment: If, by chance, you're interested in how type inference works in ML, I've given a small talk about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPVTNxiMcSU I hope the accent is bearable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To unify a variable with something means to find a value for the variable that equals that something. For example, we can unify something simple like (I'll use a triple equal to mean that the two terms must be equal):

```
a === int
```

The result of the unification is a value that we can substitute `a` for. In this case we can substitute `int` for `a` and the equation will hold (it's similar to solving systems of equations in mathematics):

```
a: int
-----------
int === int
```

Or we can unify a slightly more complicated equation:

```
a -> int === bool -> b
```

Here, we need to find the values that need to be substituted for `a` and `b` so that the equation holds. These are `bool` for `a` and `int` for `b`:

```
a: bool
b: int
---------------------------
bool -> int === bool -> int
```

I hope you've got the idea by now. In your case, the compiler has to unify this:

```
a === a list
```

Well, it's `''a` instead of just `a` in your error message, but we can neglect that for the moment. The thing is that because `a` appears on both sides, the equation is not unifyable, hence the hint in the error message (emphasis mine) "Type **variable** to be unified **occurs in type**". If we'd say that `a` must be `a list` and replace `a` with that on both sides we'd get this:

```
a list === a list list
```

We haven't removed the `a` variable that we need to solve for and we won't anytime soon. That's why the compiler barfs, it leads to an infinite loop and a simple check that the variable doesn't occur on both sides of the equation is a good way to avoid that loop.

Why does it happen in your case? The short version is that you're trying to represent a tree using nested lists and SML's type system can't handle that. The tree you're trying to build in terms of lists looks akin to this:

```
[[a], a, [a]]
```

Where `a` is some generic type variable. Lists are homogeneous containers, they can only contain values of a single type, which means that `[a]` and `a` must be of the same type, i.e.:

```
a === a list
```

And I've already explained why this leads to an error.

The solution is to use a recursive `datatype` to representing trees, such as this:

```
datatype 'a tree =
  Leaf
| Node of { value : 'a, left: 'a tree, right: 'a tree }
```

This works because it allows us to define it recursively, i.e., the type of the leaves are `tree` themselves. Your `recon` function should have `''a tree` as its return type.

Hopefully, it's a little clearer now.

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you sir! Greatly appreciated, especially coming from a professor.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan: `recon` should probably have type *''a list -> ''a list -> ''a tree* since elements are being compared with one another.

Comment: @SimonShine you're right. I just wanted to avoid explaining the difference between `'a` and `''a`, but maybe it causes more confusion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ionut gave a comprehensive explanation of how type unification works, so here is a hint:

   ```
   [preoH, recon (preoLST@preoRST, inoLST@inoRST)]
   ```

   The first element has type *'a* and the second element has type *'a list*.

   ```
   [recon (preoLST, inoLST), preoH, recon (preoRST, inoRST)]
   ```

   The second element has type *'a* and the first and third element have type *'a list*.
2. When you check lists for being empty, consider using `null preoT`, or handle the case using pattern matching.