# unification with recursive datatypes

Tags: recursion, types, sml, unification

Following the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814033/type-variable-to-be-unified-occurs-in-type/36822690#36822690) to use recursive datatypes for a nested structure like a tree I tried to make said recsurive datatyep work in a test program but encountered (yet another, very cryptic for me) error.

My program is this:

```
datatype 'a tree =
  Leaf of { value : 'a }
| Node of { value : 'a, left: 'a tree, right: 'a tree }


fun recursivetreebuilder a n =
  if n = 0
  then
      Leaf a
  else
      Node (a, recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1), recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1))
```

So, the function is supposed to build a binary tree of depth `n`, by recursively calling itself with decremented `n`s until `n` is 0.

But I am getting this error:

```
Can't unify {left: 'a tree, right: 'a tree, value: 'a} with {value: 'b} *
(Int32.int/int -> 'c) * (Int32.int/int -> 'c) (Field 1 missing) Found near if
<( n, 0) then Leaf(a) else Node( a, recursivetreebuilder( ...), ......)
```

Using recursive datatypes was intended to solve another unification issue when using nested lists. Maybe I should be able to see where the problem is given the explanation to my other question, but I don't yet.

What "Field 1" is the compiler referring to and why can't it unify when recursive datatypes was intended to make it be able to unify different "sub-types" of the same datatype?

## Edit

Tried several of the suggested structures, but still getting errors. For example for

```
datatype 'a tree =
     Leaf of 'a
     |  Node of 'a tree * 'a tree


fun recursivetreebuilder a n =
  if n < 0
  then
      Leaf (a)
  else
      Node (recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1), recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1))
```

I get

```
val printList = fn : Int.int list -> unit
Error- in 'recon_bintree.sml', line 12.
Can't unify 'a with 'a * Int32.int/int (Type variable to be unified occurs in type) Found near if
<( n, 0) then Leaf(a) else
Node( recursivetreebuilder( a, ...), recursivetreebuilder( ...))
Error- in 'recon_bintree.sml', line 12.
Can't unify 'a with 'a * Int32.int/int (Type variable to be unified occurs in type) Found near if
<( n, 0) then Leaf(a) else
Node( recursivetreebuilder( a, ...), recursivetreebuilder( ...))
Error- in 'recon_bintree.sml', line 12.
Can't unify 'a tree with Int32.int/int -> 'b (Incompatible types) Found near if
<( n, 0) then Leaf(a) else
Node( recursivetreebuilder( a, ...), recursivetreebuilder( ...))
Error- in 'recon_bintree.sml', line 12.
Can't unify 'a tree with Int32.int/int -> 'b (Incompatible types) Found near if
<( n, 0) then Leaf(a) else
Node( recursivetreebuilder( a, ...), recursivetreebuilder( ...))
Exception- Fail "Static errors (pass2)" raised
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here.

The first problem is that — for example — `{ value : 'a, left: 'a tree, right: 'a tree }` is a record type, whereas `(a, recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1), recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1))` is a tuple rather than a record. So they don't match; it's just like passing a `real` to a function expecting an `int`.

(Pedantic aside: technically tuples actually *are* records, but very specific ones; `(a, b, c)` is syntactic sugar for `{ 1 = a, 2 = b, 3 = c }`. For most practical purposes, you can just think of tuples and records as two similar-but-completely-separate ways to combine types. But now you know why the error-message referred to "Field `1`".)

The second problem is that you're declaring the function to use currying (`fun recursivetreebuilder a n = ...`), but then you try to call it with a tuple (`recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1)`).

---

One approach is to stick with your datatype definition, and keep the function using currying, and change everything to match those decisions:

```
datatype 'a tree =
  Leaf of { value : 'a }
| Node of { value : 'a, left: 'a tree, right: 'a tree }

fun recursivetreebuilder a n =
  if n = 0
  then
      Leaf { value = a}
  else
      Node { value = a,
             left = recursivetreebuilder a (n-1),
             right = recursivetreebuilder a (n-1) }
```

or change your datatype definition to eliminate the record types, and change the function to eliminate the currying:

```
datatype 'a tree =
  Leaf of 'a
| Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree

fun recursivetreebuilder (a, n) =
  if n = 0
  then
      Leaf a
  else
      Node (a, recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1), recursivetreebuilder(a, n-1))
```

or mix-and-match the above. (The fix for the record-vs.-tuple problem is independent of the fix for the currying-vs.-tuple problem.)

---

Incidentally, I think it's a mistake to include a value both in the `Leaf` case and in the `Node` case. With your current definition, it's impossible to have a tree containing exactly 0 or exactly 2 elements.

Instead, I think you should either have empty leaves:

```
datatype 'a tree =
  Leaf
| Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

or nodes that have child-nodes but no values of their own:

```
datatype 'a tree =
  Leaf of 'a
| Node of 'a tree * 'a tree
```

or eliminate the distinction between leaves and nodes, and make the children optional:

```
datatype 'a tree =
   Node of 'a * 'a tree option * 'a tree option
```

Comment: Okay, I understand... more or less. I tried implementing your second suggested structure, but I still get unification errors... what am I missing there? I updated the question.

Comment: @lotolmencre: Sorry about that. You had another problem as well, that I hadn't noticed. I've now updated the answer to explain both problems. (And this time I've tested it.)