# Standard ML, map for trees type

Tags: types, tree, sml, ml

I don't know that my code's type result.

for example,

I make a code, which makes

"maptree f (NODE (NODE ( LEAF 3, LEAF 4), LEAF 5))" to

"maptree f (NODE (NODE ( LEAF 6, LEAF 7), LEAF 8))".

My code is

```
datatype 'a tree= LEAF of 'a | NODE of 'a tree * 'a tree;
fun f(x) = x+3;
fun maptree f(NODE (X,Y))= NODE (maptree f(X), maptree f(Y))
   | maptree f(LEAF (X)) = LEAF (f X);
```

I expect that ('a -> 'a) -> 'a tree -> 'a tree.

But result is ('a -> 'b) -> 'a tree -> 'b tree.

I don't know why this is.

Comment: The type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a tree -> 'b tree` is the most general type that can be derived for your function. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814033/type-variable-to-be-unified-occurs-in-type/36814914#36814914) for a very thorough explanation of the type inference on a similar function. This post also resembles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986057/i-want-to-make-function-maptree-with-standard-ml/36986153#36986153 - please make an effort of looking for existing answers by/for your fellow students.

Comment: Oh, my gosh. I wrote this yesterday. I'm so sorry that I couldn't find similar questions. though I do effort to find similar questions. I'm so sorry

Comment: No worries, @Jang! It happens, even with the best intentions. I will move to close this question, however, as it is a near duplicate.